# mark the particular setting from my App in android

Tags: android, networking, settings

I am getting problem in my app .where i need to mark the particular `Settings` I have used the following code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

Its open the setting page but it does not mark the particular Entities.How could i get the `automark` option Could anybody help me out!!@Thanks

Comment: `it does not mark the particular Entities` i don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for your response!! it does not mark the particular Entities it means eg: i need to on the gps when my app will open

Comment: you mean you what to open the gps sub menu ? or to scroll to the gps section ? (this can vary from a device to another)

Comment: @njzk2 not submenu what i want is when i will open my app it will activate some settings automatically

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible, unless you have the rights and access the setting directly (not with an intent, but with the Settings class), and even though, I'm not sure you can.

What you can do is what google maps does. When your app starts, check if the gps is enabled, if it is not, display an alert notifying the user, with a button to quit the app, and a button to go to the settings screen. When the user comes back from Settings screen, test again.

Comment: not entirely sure, but there is probably something with LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(), to be tested in the onResume of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

If the action that you are trying to do was allowed then users would be very mad if some application would turn on their wireless connection or even worse the GPS sensor.

This change is available to change only by the user him self. So as mentioned the most you can do in case you need Internet connection or GPS sensor available is to present a user with the relevant message and fire an intent that will take them to the settings screen to change this setting them self.